# Proving distance defined is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ if distance $d(x,y) = { (x - y)^2}$,

I want to show that ${(x - y)^2} \leq {(x - z)^2} + {(z - y)^2} $. Basically, I am trying to prove that this distance satisfy triangular inequality.

I have established

$ |p \cdot q | \leq |p| \cdot |q| $

$ |p + q | \leq |p| + |q| $

$ |p - q | \leq |p| - |q| $

Problem seems to introduce $z$ in the inequality. Any hints?

I started with $(x-y)^2 = (x+z-z-y)^2$ But this doesn't lead to where I wanted to go.

A related question [Euclidean distance proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75207/euclidean-distance-proof) had confusing answer to me.

Comment: Isn't this just absolute value? (upvoted so you can comment)

Comment: in other terms $\sqrt{(x - y)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x - z)^2} + \sqrt{(z - y)^2}$ can written $|x - y| \leq |x - z|+|z - y|$...

Comment: If $ x<z<y$, RHD $=|x-y|$. Then this is obvious except this.

Comment: I am sorry, but wanted to prove that without square root. Corrected typo. Any hints?

Comment: **Hint**: try $x=0$, $z=1$, $y=2$

Comment: It is intuitive but I'm seeking hint for proof in introducing another variable in inequality.

Comment: @Exodd I think you missed the idea of what C34nm was saying. Go ahead and try his/her points.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic As already stated in the answer, it is not a distance, and I proposed a counterexample

Comment: @Exodd I got my tags mixed up and meant to point OP back to your counterexample. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a distance. Prove with $$(x,y,z)=(3,5,4)$$ In this case you have
$${(x - y)^2} \gt {(x - z)^2} + {(z - y)^2}$$