# Show that a stastistical distance is a real distance

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, statistics, vectors

> Show that a stastistical distance is a real distance.

Let $S=(s_{11},s_{22},\dots,s_{pp})$ a vector of sample variances and three vectors $X=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_p)$, $Y=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_p)$ and $W=(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_p)$. The statistical distance is defined by
$$D(X,Y)=\sqrt{\frac{(x_1-y_1)^2}{s_{11}}+\frac{(x_2-y_2)^2}{s_{22}}+\dots+\frac{(x_p-y_p)^2}{s_{pp}}}$$
So I want to show that

a) $D(X,Y)=D(Y,X)$

b) $D(X,Y)=0$ if $X=Y$

c) $D(X,Y)>0$ if $X\neq Y$

d) $D(X,Y)\leq D(X,W)+D(W,Y)$

**Proof:**

a)$$D(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{s_{ii}}=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(y_i-x_i)^2}{s_{ii}}=D(Y,X)$$

b) If $X=Y$ then $\forall i\qquad x_i=y_i$
$$D(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{s_{ii}}=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(y_i-y_i)^2}{s_{ii}}=0$$

c) If $X\neq Y$ then there is at least one $x_i\neq y_i$ then for some $i$ $(x_i-y_i)>0$ thus
$$D(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{s_{ii}}>0$$

d) Here is the problem, I need to show the triangle inequality and proof the cauchy schwarz inequality, the same argument from here [Euclidean distance proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75207/euclidean-distance-proof) hold in this case?

Comment: The $s_{jj}$ terms are the same between different random variables?

Comment: @Masacroso I'm not sure about that, but I think that not.

Comment: @Masacroso : Could you write $\|x\|$ instead of $||x||$?  Notice the conspicuous difference between $\|a\|\|b\|$ (which is standard notation coded as \|a\|\|b\|) and $||a|| ||b||$ (which is your notation, coded as ||a|| ||b||). $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that the $s_{jj}$ are equal between different random variables, as it seems to be by the wording of the problem, then squaring the formula for triangle inequality we can see that

$$\sum\frac{(x_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}\le \sum\frac{(x_j-z_j)^2}{s_{jj}}+\sum\frac{(z_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}+2\sqrt{\sum\frac{(x_j-z_j)^2}{s_{jj}}\sum\frac{(z_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}}$$

and then observe that

$$2\sqrt{\sum\frac{(x_j-z_j)^2}{s_{jj}}\sum\frac{(z_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}}\ge 2\sum\frac{|z_j-y_j||x_j-y_j|}{s_{jj}}$$

Then comparing term by term

$$\sum\frac{(x_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}\le \sum\frac{(x_j-z_j)^2}{s_{jj}}+\sum\frac{(z_j-y_j)^2}{s_{jj}}+2\sum\frac{|z_j-y_j||x_j-y_j|}{s_{jj}}$$

we can see that

$$(x_j-y_j)^2\le (x_j-z_j)^2+(z_j-y_j)^2+2|z_j-y_j||x_j-z_j|\implies\\
-x_jy_j\le z_j^2-x_jz_j-y_jz_j+|z_j-y_j||x_j-z_j|$$

I left the last statement unfinished. Check if it is true.